# ¿Como se cuando mi codigo esta mal organizado?

Tags: java

Recién estoy aprendiendo a programar y, me gustaría saber si el siguiente ejercicio esta organizado de una buena forma o esta mal, para así empezar a aprender a organizarlos. Mi duda es si quizás deba crear otra clase para realizar las operaciones que indique el usuario

CODIGO:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Permite capturar los valores que el usuario ingrese 

public class Operaciones {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        
        //------------------ESPACIO DONDE SOLICITAMOS INGRESAR UN NUMERO-------------------
        
        //Se hace el llamado a la clase Scanner para crear un objeto que nos permita capturar los valores
        Scanner opcion = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println (" - Digite un primer numero: "); //Solicitamos al usuario ingresar un numero
        float numeroUno = opcion.nextFloat(); //Permite obtener el valor ingresado por el usuario
        System.out.println (" - Digite un segundo numero: "); //Solicitamos al usuario ingresar un segundo numero
        float numeroDos = opcion.nextFloat(); //Permite obtener el segundo valor ingresado por el usuario
        
        //----------ESPACIO DONDE SOLICITAMOS ELEGIR UNA OPCION--------------
        
        Scanner opcionDos = new Scanner (System.in); //Se pretende darle la opción al usuario de realizar la operación que necesite
        System.out.println(" - Ingrese una opcion de operacion");
        System.out.println("   1 para suma, 2 para resta, 3 para multiplicacion y 4 para division: ");
        int leer = opcionDos.nextInt ();//Leera la opcion de operacion que digite el usuario 
        
        
        //-------------------ESPACIO DE OPERACIONES------------------------
        
        //Se inician unos if anidados en donde se evaluara la opcion que ingreso el usuario y decidira que operacion efectuar
        if (leer > 0 && leer<= 1 ){ //Si ingresa 1 realizar una suma 
            float respuesta =  numeroUno + numeroDos; 
            System.out.println(" " + numeroUno + " + " + numeroDos + " = " + respuesta);
        }
        else {
            if (leer > 1 && leer<= 2) { //Si ingresa 2, realizar resta
            float respuesta = numeroUno - numeroDos; 
            System.out.println(" " + numeroUno + " - " + numeroDos + " = " + respuesta);
        }
            else {
                if (leer> 2 && leer<= 3) { //Si ingresa 3, realizar multiplicacion
                    float respuesta = numeroUno * numeroDos;
                    System.out.println(" " + numeroUno + " * " + numeroDos + " = " + respuesta);
                }
                else {
                    if (leer> 3 && leer<= 4) { //Si ingresa 4 realizar division 
                        float respuesta = numeroUno / numeroDos;
                        System.out.println(" " + numeroUno + " / " + numeroDos + " = " + respuesta);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: solo necesitas un objeto scanner y es mejor usar switch-case a fin de evitar el uso de muchas condicionales if-else

Comment: Es subjetivo. En líneas generales, el código está bien organizado cuando es fácil de leer. Nada de indentado innecesario. Funciones que sean cortas (sin exagerar). Por ejemplo, tu código podría mejorarse cambiando `else { if` por  [`else if`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp)

Comment: Hola Juliana, bienvenida, en cuanto a organización, nada que decir, los bloques de decisión.... flojitos, **if ( leer > 0 && leer <= 1 ) {**... no es más fácil **if( leer == 1 )**?, y como te señalo Mateo, un if, dos else if y un else son suficientes, y si te sientes más cómoda, puedes recurrir a la idea propuesta por Dramaturgo, un switch... eso si, flojito, pero funciona, que no es poca cosa!!!.